# PHP Start script where it timed out

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm currently building a web crawler but to start I would like to test it on my shared webhosting, obviously they do not allow `set_time_limit` so I can't make sure the script keeps running for longer than 30 seconds.

What would be the best way to start the PHP script the next time where it timed out before?
I was thinking about saving the last crawled URL in a file but are there any other options?

Comment: Since you are building a web crawler, consider just storing the current crawled URL somewhere, and then if the crawler crashes you can just resume from this specific URL.

Comment: True, the problem is the script often times out before it had the chance to crawl one page.

Comment: If you save the last crawled url for resume after timeout, be sure to skip and reschedule failing urls. Otherwise you might get stuck with an infinite loop on a broken page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** ScallioXTX is right, you can't use variables as a `goto` label. You could get around that with a very large `if` statement, but at this point I'd say it's best to not use `goto` at all. Here is an alternative method:

```
<?php

    // Load label number from database or text file into $label_num
    
    if($label_num <= 1) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    
    if($label_num <= 2) {
        // Do more stuff
    }
    
    // ...

?>
```

**Old (incorrect) method:**

You can of course use `goto`: https://www.php.net/goto

I would only use this as a temporary measure until you get better hosting.

Here's what I would do:

1. At various locations throughout your code, write a label (ex. `count1:`, `count2:`, etc.)
2. At each location where you added a label, write that label name to a database or text file
3. At the beginning of your script, load that value and jump to the specified label

Example:

```
<?php

    // Load label number from database or text file into $label_num
    
    if($label_num) {
        goto $label_num;
    }
     
    count1:
    // Do stuff
    
    count2:
    // Do more stuff
    
    // ...

?>
```

Comment: -1 You can't `goto` a variable name, that gives a parse error (see comment from Ray dot Paseur at Gmail dot com in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php))

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can use this somehow, it's a bit tricky! :)